# Select option from a dropdown button using selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium

Good day. How do I select an option from a drop down menu with an html element `<span class="underlying">AUD/JPY</span>`. I have tried the recommended methods such as                 `from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select ; select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="all-accounts"]/li/a/div[1]/div[2]'));`
After running the script the console returns the message "Unable to locate element". But when I run the script through One-Line Console the drop down option is selected corectly.

```js
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

#allow pop up notifications

option = Options()
option.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
option.add_argument("start-maximized")
option.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
option.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1})

#start the webpage

browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=option, executable_path='C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\P.W\\Projects\\pythonProject2\\chromedriver')
browser.get('https://oauth.binary.com/oauth2/authorize?app_id=1&l=EN&signup_device=desktop&date_first_contact=2020-09-11')
emailbar = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtEmail"]')
emailbar.send_keys('myusername')
passwordbar = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtPass"]')
passwordbar.send_keys('password')
loginbutton = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="frmLogin"]/div[3]/button')
loginbutton.click()

#select between real account or virtual account

dropdownaccount = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main-account"]/li/a/div[2]')
dropdownaccount.click()
```

Comment: Can you share the demo set of credentials?

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with selects in Selenium, I do the following:

1. Find the select and click on it
2. Find the option you want and click on it

So for example

```
    select = driver.find_element_by_id('my_select')
    select.click()
    selected_option = driver.find_element_by_id('my_option_id')
    selected_option.click()
```

Of course, you can change the find methods to use xpath, css, etc. depending on your webpage.

Comment: True, but the problem is not selecting, its finding. it cannot find those elements

Comment: Well there are 2 possibilities. 1. Your xpath is wrong. 2. The content is dynamic and has not loaded yet. When you say "one-line console", if you are talking the browser console, then chances are your xpath is correct. If not, you could try something like:  driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(), \'AUD/JPY\')]'). For the second thing, you can use WebDriverWait() to try and wait until the content is loaded.